# Kept getting "incorrect type (expected basestring, got str)" when using peewee to create tables in sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, cython, peewee

Couldn't make `peewee` work with the simplest example:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('people.db')

class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()
    birthday = DateField()
    is_relative = BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        database = db # This model uses the "people.db" database.

class Pet(Model):
    owner = ForeignKeyField(Person, related_name='pets')
    name = CharField()
    animal_type = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = db # this model uses the "people.db" database

db.connect()
db.create_tables([Person, Pet])
```

And I got this weird error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\EclipseWorkspace\peewee_test.py", line 22, in <module>
    db.create_tables([Person, Pet])
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3448, in create_tables
    create_model_tables(models, fail_silently=safe)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 4767, in create_model_tables
    m.create_table(**create_table_kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 4459, in create_table
    db.create_table(cls)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3445, in create_table
    return self.execute_sql(*qc.create_table(model_class, safe))
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1865, in inner
    return self.parse_node(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1577, in parse_node
    sql, params, unknown = self._parse(node, alias_map, conv)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1551, in _parse
    sql, params = self._parse_map[node_type](node, alias_map, conv)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1479, in _parse_clause
    node.nodes, alias_map, conv, node.glue)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1594, in parse_node_list
    node_sql, node_params = self.parse_node(node, alias_map, conv)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1577, in parse_node
    sql, params, unknown = self._parse(node, alias_map, conv)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1551, in _parse
    sql, params = self._parse_map[node_type](node, alias_map, conv)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1481, in _parse_clause
    sql = '(%s)' % strip_parens(sql)
TypeError: Argument 's' has incorrect type (expected basestring, got str)
```

I've searched a while, and looks like it's a `cython` related problem, some suggested updating `cython` to the latest stable release, but I still got this error with `cython` **0.23.4**, anybody knows how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution for this. 
`basestring` is a new string type starting from `cython` **0.20**, and according to [peewee docs](https://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/installation.html):

> Speedups, which includes miscellaneous functions re-implemented with
>   Cython. This module will be built automatically if Cython is
>   installed.

So basically `playhouse/_speedups.pyd` was built with `cython` **0.19** during installation, and later on I did update `cython` to **0.23.4** but it won't have any effect on the file.

After reinstallation/rebuild of `peewee`, now everything works all right.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to get it working You might create tables in a loop

```
for table in [Pet, Person]: 
    db.create_table(table)
```

although I must say that I've tested this with older Cython (0.21.1) - I'll see if that's still possible after update...it is possible (0.23.4). But I see that Your Python is quite old, You might consider upgrade (2.7.10 seems to be latest bugfix 2.7.x release as of 2016.01.07)

Comment: Well, `for table in [Person, Pet]: db.create_table(table)` gives same error as before. Not really sure if it's python itself causing this problem, but do not want to update it right now because of some potential compatability problems.

Comment: If You don't want to upgrade Python then as an alternative You might need to patch `D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\site-packages\peewee.py` which i wouldn't recommend. Other than that I have no other ideas, sorry.

Comment: Solved the problem. It's actually caused by `playhouse/_speedups.pyd` which was built by a relatively lower version (0.19, to be exact) of `cython` during installation. And `basestring` was introduced in 0.20.